# After logout back/reload issue in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, logout, post-redirect-get

I have a login page (`Index.jsp`) , here user put user id and password. On submit `LoginAuthentification.java`(action class) called and authenticate the user, but according to the result in the action class it returns the JSP.

```xml
<action name="login" class="com.struts2.LoginAuthentication"
    method="execute">
    <interceptor-ref name="clear-cache" />
    <result name="manager">/ManagerView.jsp</result>
    <result name="SSE" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">viewPlan</param>
        <param name="userID">${userID}</param>
    </result>
    <result name="input">/Index.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In this case, it is returning `ManagerView.jsp`. Now in this JSP, I added a hyperlink for `logout`, and it is doing below

```xml
<action name="logout" class="com.struts2.LoginAuthentication"
    method="logout">
    <interceptor-ref name="clear-cache" />
    <result name="success">/Index.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**Code from `Action` class:**

```
public String logout() {  
    //if (session instanceof org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap) {
    session.clear();
    //session.re
    System.out.println("test");
    session.remove("loggedInUser");
   ((org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap) session).invalidate();
   
    //}  
    return "success";
}
```

after logout it is redirected to `Index.jsp`, now I clicked on back button
It display `"confirm form resubmission"` message in chrome and webpage expired in IE. But when I reload the page it login the old user automatically.
I have added

```
<%                        
  response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");           
  response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
  response.setHeader("Vary", "*");
%>
```

in the JSP as well as in interceptor.

I am trying to block auto login on reload.

Comment: Please state what error are you getting/some information that will help experts to understand the issue better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after logout you are not actually *redirect* to a new action. The cause of such behavior when you pressed the back button you got a conformation dialog in the browser. The back button is not used to call an action, unless it's not invoked via triggering it using Ajax. You should follow [post-redirect-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern when doing request for logout.

```xml
<action name="logout" class="com.struts2.LoginAuthentication" method="logout">
    <interceptor-ref name="clear-cache" />
    <result name="success" type="redirect">/</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Roman. I tried the code which you provided but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by redirecting it to another action. and wrote another interceptor to validate if it is having user id in the session or not.

```
<default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></default-interceptor-ref>
<action name="login" class="com.struts2.LoginAuthentication"
            method="execute">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            <result name="manager" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">home</param>
            </result>
</action>
<action name="home" class="com.struts2.LoginAuthentication"
            method="home">
            <result name="success">/ManagerView.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
```