# IE 11 browser back button throws NullPointerException

Tags: internet-explorer, struts2, back

I am working on Struts 2 based application, which is running fine in Chrome and Mozilla firefox, but in IE 11 what happening is, when I hit IE's back button it firstly shows an exception as shown below

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/ComparativeSiteAnalysis.jsp at line 97

94:     <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
95:       <tr>
96:         <td width="19%" class="chart_head_1">&nbsp;</td>
97:         <td width="81%" colspan="7" class="chart_head_1"><%=((String)request.getAttribute("divName")).replace(" ","&nbsp;")%> <%= manager.getValue(langSelected+AppConstants.HEADING_COMPARATIVE_CHART) %></td>
98:        <td align="right" ><a href="#" onclick="back();" class="back_link"><img src="./images/Right Arrow.png" width="12" height="12" border="0" />&nbsp;<%= manager.getValue(langSelected+AppConstants.BACK) %></a></td></tr>
99:       <tr>
100:         <td class="chart_head_2" colspan="9">


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:154)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:361)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:265)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
    org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)



root cause 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.jsp.ComparativeSiteAnalysis_jsp._jspService(ComparativeSiteAnalysis_jsp.java:214)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
```

**BACKEND CODE**

```
   @Override
    public String getComparativeSiteAnalysis(Integer divId, String lang, int selectedYear) {
        // System.out .println("getComparativeSiteAnalysis lang="+lang);
        maxSizeSiteName = "";
        if (divId != null) {
            List<Frequency> freqList = null;
            List<Site> sites = null;
            int year = -1;
            try {
                //PLEANTY OF CODE
            } catch (CustomException e) {

                logger.error("Error in getComparativeSiteAnalysis Method", e);
            }
            if (sites == null || sites.isEmpty()) {
                return "";
            }
            dataCount = sites.size();
            // System.out.println("dataCount:"+dataCount);
            List<String> colList = new ArrayList<String>();


            Collections.sort(sites, new UniversalComparator("isStatus", 1));

            for (Iterator<Site> iterator = sites.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                site = iterator.next();
                if (site.getName().length() > maxSizeSiteName.length()) {
                    maxSizeSiteName = site.getName();
                }
                int naSiteDataCount = 0;
                logger.debug("SITE NAME===>>" + site.getName());
                Utility.getInstance().computeSite(site, true, null, false, null, year);

                // System.out.println(" sitename: "+site.getName()+" semi annual compliance:
                // "+site.getSemiAnnualCompliance());

                String link = "JavaScript:getSiteWiseMonthlyChapterAnalysis('"
                        + StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(site.getName()) + "'," + site.getId() + ","
                        + manager.getValue(AppConstants.MONTHLY) + ",'" + monthlyFreqName + "')";

                rowList.add(site.getName());
                siteComparativeChart = utility.addHeapMapDataSetNode(site.getName(), monthlyFreqName,
                        String.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(site.getMonthlyCompliance())), link, siteComparativeChart,
                        site.getComparativeColorMonthly());
                int monthlyDataCount = site.getComparativeColorMonthly().equalsIgnoreCase("White") ? 1 : 0;

                link = "JavaScript:getSiteWiseQuarterlyChapterAnalysis('" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(site.getName())
                        + "'," + site.getId() + "," + manager.getValue(AppConstants.QUATERLY) + ",'" + quaterlyFreqName
                        + "')";

                siteComparativeChart = utility.addHeapMapDataSetNode(site.getName(), quaterlyFreqName,
                        String.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(site.getQuarterlyCompliance())), link, siteComparativeChart,
                        site.getComparativeColorQuarterly());
                int quaterlyDataCount = site.getComparativeColorQuarterly().equalsIgnoreCase("White") ? 1 : 0;

                link = "JavaScript:getSiteWiseSemiAnnualChapterAnalysis('" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(site.getName())
                        + "'," + site.getId() + "," + manager.getValue(AppConstants.SEMI_ANNUAL) + ",'"
                        + semiAnnualFreqName + "')";

                siteComparativeChart = utility.addHeapMapDataSetNode(site.getName(), semiAnnualFreqName,
                        String.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(site.getSemiAnnualCompliance())), link, siteComparativeChart,
                        site.getComparativeColorSemiAnnual());
                int semiAnnualDataCount = site.getComparativeColorSemiAnnual().equalsIgnoreCase("White") ? 1 : 0;

                link = "JavaScript:getSiteWiseAnnualChapterAnalysis('" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(site.getName())
                        + "'," + site.getId() + "," + manager.getValue(AppConstants.ANNUAL) + ",'" + annualFreqName
                        + "')";

                siteComparativeChart = utility.addHeapMapDataSetNode(site.getName(), annualFreqName,
                        String.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(site.getAnnualCompliance())), link, siteComparativeChart,
                        site.getComparativeColorAnnual());

                int annualDataCount = site.getComparativeColorAnnual().equalsIgnoreCase("White") ? 1 : 0;
                naSiteDataCount = monthlyDataCount + quaterlyDataCount + semiAnnualDataCount + annualDataCount;
                naSiteDataList.add(naSiteDataCount);
                naSiteCounter.add(naSiteDataCount);
                site.setNaSiteCount(naSiteDataList);
                site.setNaSiteCounter(naSiteCounter);
                System.out.println("datacount is" + naSiteDataCount);
            }
//          Collections.sort(sites, new UniversalComparator("getNaSiteCount", 1));
            for (Integer count : site.getNaSiteCount()) {
                System.out.println("ALL NA COUNT" + count);
            }
            for (Integer count1 : site.getNaSiteCounter()) {
                System.out.println("ALL NA COUNT" + count1);
            }
            this.maxSizeSiteName = maxSizeSiteName.replaceAll(" ", ".");
            this.maxSizeSiteName = maxSizeSiteName.replaceAll("-", ".");
            String xml = utility.getHeapMapXML1(manager.getValue(lang + AppConstants.LABEL_FREQUENCY),
                    divisionName + "-" + manager.getValue(lang + AppConstants.LABEL_SITES), colList, rowList, "0",
                    siteComparativeChart);
            return xml;
        }
        return "";

    }
```

When I hit browser's back button, the above method is invoked, what I found that `if (divId != null)` it actually returning `null` it becomes `false` and hence `return ""`

Hitting one more time, it renders the page, I don't able to figure it out what exactly the issue is, infact I ran my application in opera,safari,chrome and mozilla, none of the browser shows such disgusting exceptions.

is this is browser's issue
How do I rectify?
Any help appreciated

Comment: If possible than can you please inform us what error message you got on IE browser console? It can give some hint about the issue.

Comment: The issue will be related to caching and browsers doing different things: be explicit about caching in your headers, e.g., either force a reload or don't. Tracking down the specific issue is trivial--it tells you precisely in the JSP where the NPE is occurring.

Comment: Hey Dave, I want to know how do I perform the caching related task to prevent this can you post some blog or small snippet to achieve the same

Comment: Hey Deepak, i pasted the trace from IE browser itsel

Comment: This is an error which should be fixed on the server, not on the client, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/28669573/573032

Comment: Hey Roman C, this exception only occured in IE 11 browser, I tested in every browser and my application didn't complaint there

Comment: @user9634982, If there is any sample code to produce the issue than please try to provide. We will try to make a test with it and try to check for the issue. It can help us to understand the issue in better way.

Comment: Hey Deepak I have just added the new trace

Comment: Is there any simple way to produce this issue? So that we can try to test the issue with IE.

Comment: I have followed the simple way to produce the same, deploy the application, navigate to the sub pages and hit the browser's back button

Comment: I have added the backend code which is responsible to handle and render the page

Comment: did you check on your side whether you are passing any NULL parameter or value in any function created by you or someone else? It can caused this issue. Try to debug your code may help to find the problematic line.

Comment: Agreed but I am wondering that why it will work, when I hit back button second time, at first time it shows exception, another time I pressed the same and it is working like a charm

Comment: If you had tried debugging the app with IE than can you please inform us your results may help us to get any further ideas about the issue.

Comment: What I figured out is the requested URL is not able to build in IE 11 first time when browser back button is pressed, while in other browsers its working like charm

Comment: When I navigated back from `siteWiseAnnualChapterAnalysis.action` to `comparativeSiteAnalysis.action` on first press, then it complaints on line 97 `<td width="81%" colspan="7" class="chart_head_1"><%=((String)request.getAttribute("divName")).replace(" ","&nbsp;")%> <%= manager.getValue(langSelected+AppConstants.HEADING_COMPARATIVE_CHART) %></td> ` and long exception trace displayed in browser

Comment: But when I hit back button second time, and now its just like magic, its working fine, I think its not able to construct the URL properly

Comment: I suggest you to make a test on any other machine to check whether it is working there or not. It can be possible that this issue is related with specific machine and on other machines it is working fine. This test can help you to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Deepak it seems like IE conflicting with same name variable, as per my experience,  I found that IE read JS very deeply, may be its not able to resolve the conflict occurs in variable names. It hits the action while clicking on back button, which should not be happened.